# PyQt Designer where to write code?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have PyQT v.4.8.8 installed.When I draw layouts and I want to view the code , it comes with error that is unable to launch uic as in snapshot:

[image]

I can compile the .ui files manually in cmdLine. But I dont know where to put the code for slot,methods ,signals.

1- Where should I set the settings for finding uic to compile ui? My installation does not have pyuic4.

2 - Where can I define my own slots/methods and functoins signatures ? (receiver object,sender) I can see the Edit signals/slots in edit menu but that only shows standard signals/slots.Doesn't have options to define yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [tutorial](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/simple-text-editor-pyqt4/) for PyQt4 explaining how to add your own slots in Qt4.Very informative.

Answer (score 11):

As the name says, the Qt designer is for interface *design* only.  You cannot use it to write the code for the actual application logic.  For this, you'll need a normal Python editor.  The exact details on how to use designer files in Python are explained in [PyQt reference guide, Using Qt Designer](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html).

Btw, `uic` is not for PyQt, but for compiling user interfaces into C++.  To compile user interfaces to Python, you need to use `pyuic4`.  This tool cannot be run from the designer, you need to run it manually.  But it is recommended to load the user interface dynamically at runtime using the `PyQt4.uic` modules as explained in the reference guide.

Comment: I was following this tutorial at        http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~afedosov/qttut/


It shows a section where you can define your functions signatures which I cant find it in QtDesigner I have.I understand I cant write the code in designer but I should be able to degine new methods/slots.

When I install pyQt it doesnt come with pyuic4. but with uic I can generate python codes actually..

Comment: @Arash. That tutorial is for PyQt3 not PyQt4.

Comment: It seems Designer 4 competley removes that feature.

Comment: That's because Qt Creator is boss.